# Does the compiler feature of Closures decrease member variable security?

Tags: appsec, source-code, .net

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928636/how-do-closures-work-behind-the-scenes-c/1928793#1928793) discussion, closures in C# promote private variables to public variables at compile time.

Suppose a closure was implemented on a Username or Password string.  Would there be any security issue with this at run time?  Is this an issue in any other language?

If so, is there any way I can prevent this (via attributes)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite the visibility promotion, Closures do not present any new security issue.

This is because of the simple reason, that visibility (i.e. private/public) is *not a security mechanism* in the first place.
Just because you marked your password field as `private`, doesnt mean it is not accessible. It's **not** accessible, but only to code that behaves nicely.
It's still accessible easily in code, e.g. via reflection. (Of course, consumers of your class *shouldn't* do that...)

And that's even without going into things like debugging, memory inspection, etc...

So - as I said, it doesnt affect the level of security. You'd need to protect that Password field, but you'd need to do that anyway.
(Suggestion: store passwords as `SecureString` instead of strings... )